# Logical replication from Postgresql to Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, data-migration, greenplum

We have a Postgresql database to which we are only adding data (we don't use UPDATE or DELETE operations). We need to perform analytical queries on the data that we received a few minutes ago. We decided to use Greenplum form that. The data flow looks like that: we create replication slots on postgresql, use Debezium to receive changes from postgresql and then send them to Greenplum. How to configure Debezium for that? Is there any other solutions to replicate data from postgres to greenplum near real time?

Comment: Why you want to use Debezium when you can achieve the same task using PG as publisher (with logical replication) and Greenplum as a Subscriber. You need pgoutput plugin for Greenplum and by creating a foreign table in Greenplum that represents the table(s) you want to replicate.